# How to setup serverless.yml and webpack.config for a multiple-runtime AWS Lambda service

Tags: node.js, ruby, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless-webpack-plugin

I want to deploy AWS Lambda functions with Node8.10 and Ruby2.5 runtimes from one serverless.yml file.

I set up the following folder structure, with /node and /ruby holding my respective handlers.

```
 -/nodeRubyLambdas
  -/node
    -handler.js
    -package.json, package-lock.json, /node_modules
  -/ruby
    -rubyRijndaelEncryption.rb
    -Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, /vendor
  -serverless.yml
  -webpack.config.js
  -package.json for serverless-webpack
```

Here is my serverless.yml

```
service: nodeRubyLambdas

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
      Resource: "*"

  package:
    individually: true

functions:
  nodeMain:
    handler: node/handler.main
    runtime: nodejs8.10
    events:
      - http:
          path: main
          method: get
    package:
      individually: true
  rubyEncryption:
    handler: ruby/rubyRijndaelEncryption.lambda_handler
    runtime: ruby2.5
    environment:
      RIJNDAEL_PASSWORD: 'a string'
    package:
      individually: true
```

My webpack configuration: (This is the base example, I just added the bit to ignore ruby files when I got my first error.)

```
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: "node",
  // Generate sourcemaps for proper error messages
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? "development" : "production",
  optimization: {
   // We do not want to minimize our code.
   minimize: false
  },
  performance: {
    // Turn off size warnings for entry points
    hints: false
  },
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.rb$/]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**Fail #0:**
    [Webpack Compilation error] Module parse failed

**Fail #1:**
Basically, webpack assumes all functions are .js and tries to package them as such.  Based off [this suggestion](https://forum.serverless.com/t/how-to-create-a-multi-language-serverless-setup/5222), I forced my entry point in webpack config to be my handler.js

```
 module.exports = {
  entry: "./node/handler.js",
  target: "node",
  ...
```

This packages ONLY the Node Lambda.  An empty placeholder for the Ruby Lambda is created on AWS.

**Fail #2:**
I commented out webpack from serverless.yml and added include and exclude statements in the functions package options.

```
functions:
  nodeMain:

    package:
      individually: true
      include:
        - node/**
        - handler.js
      exclude:
        - ruby/**
        - rubyLambda/**
  rubyEncryption:

    package:
      individually: true
      include:
        - vendor/**
        - rubyRijndaelEncryption.rb
      exclude:
        - Gemfile
        - Gemfile.lock
        - node/**
```

This gets an [ENOENT: no such file or directory] for node/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/.bin/parser.  This file is not there but I don't understand why it is looking for it, since webpack is not being called.

**Sort of success?:**
 I was able to get the Lambdas to deploy if I commented out webpack and used

```
    serverless deploy function -f <function name here>
```

to deploy the Ruby Lambda and then uncommented webpack and used the same thing to deploy the Node Lambda.

**I'm convinced that there's a better way to get them to deploy; Have I missed something in my setup?  Is there another option I haven't tried?**

P.S.  I did see this pull request https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/pull/256, but it seems to be abandoned since 2017.

Comment: The cause of the error in Fail #2 was that I had a node_modules directory inside another directory.  When I pulled both my package.json and Gemfile into the base folder I was able to deploy the Lambdas and perform successful tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serverless-webpack` is not designed for non-JS runtimes. It hijacks `serverless` packaging and deploys ONLY the webpack output.

Here are your options:

1. Don't use `serverless-webpack` and simply use `serverless`' built-in packaging.
2. You can use `webpack` directly (not `serverless-webpack`), and change your build process to compile using `webpack` first and then let `serverless` deploy the output folder.

P.S. The `package.individually` property is a root-level property in your `serverless.yml`. It shouldn't be in `provider` or in your function definitions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm traveling down the 1st path you suggested and will look into the 2nd.  I didn't notice that package had the wrong indentation.  I added the function level include/exclude based on the "Packaging functions separately" section in the [docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/#excluding-files-from-packaging) .

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be looking for options for multiple-runtimes other than serverless-webpack, I ended up switching to this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-include-dependencies.
It works with my runtimes (Ruby and Node) and lets you use package.individually with package.include/exclude at the root and function level if the plugin misses something.